# Django list filter not having any effect

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have some list filters that I have created. All of them work except one. Classes have a foreign key to students. I want to filter students based on whether or not they have added any classes. The code is:

```
class ClassesAddedListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('has added classes')

    parameter_name = 'classes'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
                (1, 'Has Classes'),
                (0, 'No Classes')
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value == 1:
            return queryset.annotate(class_count = Count('class')).filter(class_count__gt=0)
        if self.value == 0:
            return queryset.annotate(class_count = Count('class')).filter(class_count=0)
```

The filter renders correctly in admin interface and when I click on one of the filter options, it seems like it's working (loads new page with get parameter) but no filtering takes place (it returns all the instances even though some have no classes). I have checked the filter I am applying in the shell and it does what I intend. Can anyone help me with what I am missing?

Comment: Try with `def get_queryset(...)`

Comment: Ah I'm an idiot. I've been looking at it for 2 hours but just realised its because I left brackets off from `self.value()`

Answer (score 0):

Stupid mistake. I needed to have:

```
class ClassesAddedListFilter(admin.SimpleListFilter):
    title = _('has added classes')

    parameter_name = 'classes'

    def lookups(self, request, model_admin):
        return (
                (1, 'Has Classes'),
                (0, 'No Classes')
        )

    def queryset(self, request, queryset):
        if self.value() == 1:
            return queryset.annotate(class_count = Count('class')).filter(class_count__gt=0)
        if self.value() == 0:
            return queryset.annotate(class_count = Count('class')).filter(class_count=0)
```

Note the ()s on the end of `self.value()` to actually evaluate the function.